# Java Fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, arrays

Write a program to calculate the first 10 Fibonacci numbers and store the results in a one-dimensional array. In a second array calculate and store the average values of the adjacent numbers in the series. The first array should contain integer values and the second floating point values. Output the contents of both arrays in a neat format

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     //number of elements to generate in a series
     int limit = 10;

     long[] series = new long[limit];

     //create first 2 series elements
     series[0] = 1;
     series[1] = 1;

     //create the Fibonacci series and store it in an array
     for(int i=2; i < limit; i++){
         series[i] = series[i-1] + series[i-2];
     }

     //print the Fibonacci series numbers
     System.out.println("Fibonacci Series upto " + limit);
     for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
         System.out.print(series[i] + " ");
     }
}
```

Okay so the first part is working fine but now to create an array to calculate the average is a bit tricky for me.So far I tried this.

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55};
int sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length ; i++) {        
     sum = (int) (sum + numbers[i]);
     double average = (double)sum/numbers.length;
     System.out.println("Average value of array elements is : " + average);
}
```

But its not working quite well.Can someone offer me some light on this ?

Comment: A) you want us to spend our time to help you ; so you please spend the few minutes it takes to properly **format** you input! B) "is not working" is a pretty useless term. What exactly is not working. In other words: please turn to the help center and read "how to ask"

Comment: You want to put your `average` calculation and printing outside the loop.

Comment: It says "store the average values of the adjacent numbers in the series" i.e. `(series[i] + series[i+1])/2.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not calculate the average inside the `for loop`. Move your `average` outside of the loop so it calculates once `sum` is accurate.

```
            int[] numbers = new int[]{1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55};
            int sum=0;
            for(int i=0; i < numbers.length ; i++){        
                 sum = (int) (sum + numbers[i]);
            }
            double average = (double)sum/numbers.length;
            System.out.println("Average value of array elements is : " + average);
```

Comment: What if you want to initialize the array with the series[i] instead of int[] numbers = new int[]{1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55};
How we change that ?

Comment: You could do `int[] numbers = new int[limit]` and then in a `for loop` you should set each `numbers[i] = series[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55};
int sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {        
     sum = (int) (sum + numbers[i]);
     double average = sum/2.0;
     System.out.println("Average value of array elements is : " + average);
}
```